# How to create date in actionscript with particular timezone?

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am working on Flex 3 application, and I would like to know how can I create Date object in actionscript3 that would represent particular timezone? My application is used internationally  and I would like to create standard timezone for entire application, where as per research I found that I cannot create date object based on particular timezone. Any suggestions for this?
and FYI all business logic resided on Java on server and for front end we are using flex.

UPDATE:

I am getting time from server to flex as "Fri Sep 28 05:16:37 EDT 2012" but when I instantiate in new Date(), its throwing me invalid date error. So I corrected it as "Fri Sep 28 05:16:37 GMT -0400 2012" and instantiated with new Date(), but results I get in IST, so timezone information lost. How can I preserve timezone in flex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to store things as UTC....

In your server you can set the JVM parameter

```
-Duser.timezone=UTC
```

This will force the server to run as UTC regardless of the timezone of the computer.

Then as you are passing objects back from flex to java you will have to update the date object. Something like

```
 var utcDate:Date = new Date(d.valueOf() - (d.timezoneOffset * MS_OF_ONE_MIN));
```

where d is your Date from flex and has the timezone of the PC Flex is running on.

If you are using something like BlazeDS then you can call a function to convert all your dates in the [RemoteObject](http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/help.html?content=rpc_remoteobject_2.html) as that is your object that does the serialisation.

The big problem you have is that there is no setTimezone on a flex Date object which means you have to jump through all these hoops to get a UTC date.

Comment: Hmm thanks RNJ... but Changing anything on server (like -DUser.timezone=UTC etc) are ruled out, because its too big application and changing server side cannot be accomplished easily.. :(

Comment: @pradeepsimha then I think you may be stuck. Not have a setTimezone on date makes things really hard. Perhaps you can create your own Date object which wraps the flex object. The you could manipulate the dte and time inside that according to the timezone

Comment: @RNJ... yes, I am planning to suggest client the same thing... Initially I thought this was easy, but things are getting complicated now..

Comment: @pradeepsimha life is never easy ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use UTC fields out of Date object to receive uniform time. Then, you can use getTimezoneOffset() to receive how far is current computer from UTC. Otherwise, please clarify your question, I can't decipher what do you actually need besides operating strictly in UTC data from local Date objects.

Comment: What I need is server side code runs on EDT/EST timings and client code(flex UI) runs on IST timezone. So when user selects date from UI, it will be in IST. What I want is in UI whenever user selects Date, it should be in server time zone and not in client's time zone.

Comment: Sure, use UTC dates. When you create a Date object client-side, based on YMDhms, you receive a localized date, and if your Flash detects IST, that date will be IST. Server-side code should operate only UTC dates this way, and to pass an UTC date you just need to use UTC date functions. Ignore server-side timezone totally.

Comment: If you need a method to transfer a Date object into a given server-side zone, you first have to pass it to client somehow, then make an UTC date using given client input (`setUTCDate()` etc) and then plainly add hours to comply with server-side zone.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, nothing should care about your server-side time zone - including your server. The server location is very unlikely to have any useful business meaning, and it can be *very* useful to be able to run servers wherever you want to.

Instead, you need to work out what your UI is really representing. Is it a *local date and time* which is actually time zone neutral? Is it "just a date" which again would be time zone neutral? Is it a particular *instant* in time (e.g. when a specific phone call occurred, regardless of where it occurred)? (There are more options, but these are the most common ones.)

Once you've worked out what your data really means, you can work out the right way to transmit that to the server (you haven't told us anything about that), and then how to represent it on the server. Your server-side code will end up being a lot clearer if you use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead of the built-in `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` classes... you can represent each of the concepts listed above with an appropriate Joda Time type.

As I say though, the first thing to jettison is the idea that you should really be working in the server time zone - or at least, you'd have to justify that as an extremely unusual and potentially costly decision.